# Multi-variable function bijection proof

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

$f:\mathbb{Z}$ $\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(x)=mx^3 - nx$, where $m, n \in \mathbb{Z} $ and $m\nmid n$.

I am trying to prove whether or not the function is injective/subjective without Calculus. How can I improve this?

Injectivity:

Suppose $f(a) = f(b)$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$ma^3-na = mb^3-nb \iff ma^3-mb^3 = na-nb \iff m(a^3-b^3) = n(a-b) \iff m(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=n(a-b)$.

Case 1) $a-b=0$. Then $a=b$

Case 2) $a-b \not= 0$. Then $m(a^2+ab+b^2)=n \iff a^2+ab+b^2 = \frac{n}{m}$. Contradiction.

Taking case 1), therefore f is injective.

Surjectivity:

Case 1) Let $m=0$. Then $f(x)=-nx$. Suppose $f(a)=b$. Then $-na=b \iff a=-\frac{b}{n}$. For the function to be subjective, $n$ must be equal to either $1$ or $-1$. Otherwise, $a$ will not be in the codomain $\mathbb{Z}$.

Case 2) Let $m\not=0$. Then $f(x)=mx^3-nx$. If $GCD(m,n)=1$, then there exists, for every M, exactly one pair a,b such that $ax +by=M$.

Comment: How are you concluding the surjective counterexample?

Comment: Edited. @Shahab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof of injectivity is very good, well done!

---

Your counterexample for surjectivity, however, is nonsensical. All you did was prove that $f(2)$ is some number. You didn't prove that there exists some number $z$ for which $f(x)\neq z$ no matter what $x$ is.

In other words, to prove that $f:A\to B$ is *not* surjective, you must prove the following statement:

$$\exists b\in B: \forall a\in A: f(a)\neq b.$$

---

Guidelines regarding surjectivity:

In general, surjectivity of the function will depend on the choice of $m,n$. In particular, taking $m=0,n=1$ means the function is surjective, while taking $m=4,n=2$ means it is not (because it only has even values).

Further hints:

I would split the cases a little.

1. If $m=0$, then it should be relatively easy to show if the function is surjective or not. In particular, it is surjective if $n=1$ or $n=-1$, otherwise, it is not.
2. If $m\neq 0$, then again, consider two subcases. If $m$ and $n$ have a common divisor, it is again easy to see that the function is *not* surjective (why?)
3. The only remaining case is that $m\neq 0$ and $\mathrm{GCD}(m,n)=1$. In that case, I would use the fact that if the GCD of $x,y$ is $1$, then there exists, for every $M$, exactly one pair $a,b$ such that $ax+by=M$. It should be possible to prove that in this case, the function also cannot be surjective.

**EDIT**:

Your proof of surjectivity is still flawed. It has the right idea, but needs more structure.

> Case 1) Let $m=0$. Then $f(x)=-nx$. Suppose $f(a)=b$. Then $-na=b \iff a=-\frac{b}{n}$. For the function to be subjective, $n$ must be equal to either $1$ or $-1$. Otherwise, $a$ will not be in the codomain $\mathbb{Z}$.

The reasoning above is wrong. It is perfectly possible for $\frac bn$ to be in the domain of $f$. For example, if $b=4$ and $n=2$, then $a=2\in\mathbb Z$.

What you **need** to do to prove that the function is not surjective is this:

> There exists some $b\in\mathbb Z$ such that, for all $a\in\mathbb Z$, we have $f(a)\neq b$.

For case 2, you didn't really prove anything as well.

Comment: I've edited my post; however, am I still going the wrong way?

Comment: @blacknapkins7 I added a couple of hints.

Comment: This is an arbitrary question but what year (student) would you expect a problem like this to be given to?

Comment: @blacknapkins7 I would expect a good high-school student to be able to solve this, as it doesn't really require any advanced mathematics, only a little out-of-the-box thinking. At university, if a student struggled a lot with this problem, I would say they need to reconsider their approach to studying.

Comment: @blacknapkins7 Your argument, as it is written, is still wrong by the way. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Darn. I'm a second-year undergraduate, but my previous education hasn't been very good. I almost always feel stuck in a box when doing math problems that are less computation/more thinking. How can I overcome this?

Comment: @blacknapkins7 Well you did half the exercise, so don't beat yourself up too much. As for overcoming it, practice, practice, practice. What works best is very individual dependent, but it always involves practice.